# Wix Can you make an iframe full height and width of page

Tags: velo

I have a client who hired me to make them a single page website. I designed and programmed it in node and such. They then informed me that they had a wix account.

Since they already paid wix for a year I would like to try to make this work for them. Since you cannot upload files to wix I have it hosted on a different domain and have an iframe pointing to that domain within the page.

The only problem is the size of the iframe. Is there a way to make the iframe 100% height and 100% width? Obviously, this is not the idea way to put up a website, but I need to work with what I have so they don't waste money.

I've tried many different ways to make this work.

I have tried embedding a link to a css file using the 'embed' feature with this code in it. And the code is there, but I get iframe-ception.

```
wix-iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

I have also tried added the css to the 'custom code' section under the settings, just very basic

```
<style>
wix-iframe {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

iframe {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```

I've also tried other 'hacks' but I can't seem to get anything to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We just bumped into the same issue, since WIX won't let us define the height of the iframe (because it's inside another frame with pixel height), what we end up doing is this.

Make the iframe as large as you can so everything fits inside the frame (we made it about 8000px in height). Also we added an "overflow: hidden;" on the iframe so we won't have double scrollbars.

This way the user is scrolling the body's scrollbar and the iframe just fits perfectly inside.

Answer (score 0):

Embed site element with height set to 100 vh (viewport's height)

Answer (score -2):

You can adjust iframe height according to its content

Initialize your iframe like this

```
<iframe src="..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="loadIframe(this);" />
```

add the snippet below in your `<head>` or `<footer>`

```
<script>
  function loadIframe(elem) {
    elem.style.height = 
       elem.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work within wix/velo. You have no access to the html or the head or footer

Comment: you can convert it in one liner `onload='javascript:(function(o){o.style.height=o.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight+"px";}(this));' `

Comment: You don't have access at all to the onload part of the iframe in wix. You don't have access to any of the html